# How to upgrade drupal theme

Tags: drupal-7

In Drupal7, besides updating theme from admin which requires FTP, can I just rename the old theme folder and drop in the new version theme folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be following the below steps:

1. Firstly uninstall the theme
2. Then remove the folder
3. And then upload the new theme
4. And finally enable the theme.

Note: dont forget to keep the old theme folder as a backup before replacing it with new theme, just in case some css, images or js can break your site

Comment: One thing I want to add, might be just related to bootstrap theme itself plus used as a parent theme, I must set the group permission to writable so I can see the version number bumped up after upgrade. Can't explain why.